# General word for element in binary relation

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to denote an element in a binary relation, which in itself would connote the duality of the relationship. For example, a binary relation is the one between the east and the west half of a sphere so we call each a [hemisphere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hemisphere):

> From Latin hemisphaerium, from Ancient Greek ἡμισφαίριον (hēmisphaírion), from ἡμι- (hēmi-, “half”) + σφαῖρα (sphaîra, “sphere”); hemi- +‎ sphere

So I am looking for a more abstract/general word (that could be applied to something other than a sphere) that would indicate that the entity in question is **one of the two sides in a binary relation** and would like that word to unambiguously mean that (and remove the possibility of having more than two sides) and that it's not necessarily *half* because that implies a 50/50 split, which shouldn't be implied by that word.

Another example could be the word *wife* meaning (in a traditional sense) one of the two spouses in a marital binary relation: *"the wife is a [X] of the marriage"*

Comment: The best I could do is _choice_ and _option_, neither of which implies a binary set of options.

Comment: I'm sorry, that won't cut it

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to exclude those answers explicitly for you.  As a side note, _wife_ is not _always_ an example of your desired word.  8^)

Comment: The two sides of a binary relation (or any relation) are *sets*. One side is sometimes called the *domain* (of the relation); the other is sometimes called the *range* (of the relation).

Comment: If you want the math, formal choice, it would be exactly as you have presented it, an _element_. A relation is an ordered pair on a set, so one side of a the pair is a member of the set, which is called an _element_. But if you want to fill the slot, "the wife is a _member_ of a marriage" is more natural.

Comment: Well you could go with any one element of a quintessential pair. **yin**  for example (or **yang** for that matter)

Comment: @Mitch - Please make it an answer.  Looks good to me.

Answer (score 3):

Specifically in a relationship where there are only two things, both items are each other's [complement](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complement):

> **complement**
>
> 1c: one of two mutually completing parts

In the case of 2 things, it's unambiguous, but the idea can apply to more than 2 items in mathematics. For example, if there are 10 possible items but only 3 exist right now, the complement of those things is 7 items, which is how many would be required to make the whole (ten items).

Comment: looks promising...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the mathematical, formal choice, it would be exactly as you have presented it, an **element**. A relation is an ordered pair on a set, so one side of a the pair is a member of the set, which is called an element.

> The wife is one **element** of a pair that forms a marriage

But if you want to fill the slot in normal everyday language there are many possibilities but I find **member** sounds the most natural and generic

> The wife is a **member** of a marriage.

Other possibilities are 'partner', 'one side', 'spouse' (specific to marriage). I think the best answer will almost always depend on the context.

Comment: None of those actually connote duality

Comment: @amphibient Can you give another sentence with a slot where that connotation would be appropriate?